# Column that shows number of elements in another col (Int Array) SQL (postgres 8.3)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column of Int Array. I want to add another column to the table, that always shows the number elements in that array for that row. It should update this value automatically. Is there a way to embedd a function as default value? If so, how would this function know where to pick its argument (the int array column/row number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a normalized table you would not include this functionally dependent and redundant information as a separate column.

It is easy and fast enough to compute it on the fly:

```
SELECT array_dims ('{1,2,3}'::int[]);
```

Or:

```
SELECT array_length('{1,2,3}'::int[], 1);
```

`array_length()` has been introduced with PostgreSQL 8.4. Maybe an incentive to upgrade? [8.3 is going out of service soon.](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

With Postgres 8.3 you can use:

```
SELECT array_upper('{1,2,3}'::int[], 1);
```

But that's inferior, because the array index can start with any number, if entered explicitly. `array_upper()` would not tell the actual length then, you would have to subtract `array_lower()` first. Also note, that in PostgreSQL arrays can always contain multiple dimensions, regardless of how many dimensions have been declared. I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html#ARRAYS-DECLARATION):

> The current implementation does not enforce the declared number of
>   dimensions either. Arrays of a particular element type are all
>   considered to be of the same type, regardless of size or number of
>   dimensions. So, declaring the array size or number of dimensions in
>   CREATE TABLE is simply documentation; it does not affect run-time
>   behavior.

(True for 8.3 and 9.1 alike.) That's why I mentioned `array_dims()` first, to give a complete picture.

Details about [array functions in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE).

---

You may want to create a [**view**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) to include that functionally dependent column:

```
CREATE VIEW v_tbl AS
SELECT arr_col, array_length(arr_col, 1) AS arr_len
FROM   tbl;
```